# Calcular porcentagens diversas

Tags: matemática

Eu tenho um sistema de vendas, onde cada usuário tem uma porcentagem X sobre sua venda, no momento tenho 15 usuários, sendo 10 deles com 5% de lucro sobre cada venda, e os outros 5 tem 8% de lucro sobre cada venda.
Tenho então minha página de administração onde vejo quanto terei que pagar a todos eles se somar todas as porcentagens de ganho, o problema é que tenho que fazer o calculo venda por venda, ou seja, se o usuário tem 5% de lucro e o outro tem 8%, tenho que no `script` fazer o seguinte:

```
$Valor += $ValorDoProduto * ($GanhoDoUsuario / 100);
```

Assim, se eu somar todos os usuários, terei um valor X que representa o valor que pagarei se somar todos os ganhos de cada usuário.
Mas gostaria de fazer isso mais simples, de forma que eu calculasse todas as vendas, me retornando então um valor X, esse valor X é as vendas sem tirar o ganho do vendedor, então, quando eu tiver o valor X que é a soma de todos os produtos vendidos eu iria somar todas as porcentagens, e então subtrair e ter o mesmo valor que teria usando o cálculo lá em cima.
Explicando melhor:
Tenho uma tabela de usuários no `MySQL`, cada usuário tem um ganho em porcentagem pra cada venda, existe a possibilidade de 'somar' todas as porcentagens e então fazer um cálculo único pra determinar o quanto terei que pagar de comissão à todos eles?

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível. Se somares os valores de todos os produtos deixas de saber que parte dos lucros totais corresponde aos ganhos de 5% ou aos de 8%.

No máximo podes somar todas as vendas dos utilizadores de cada subgrupo (sendo um subgrupo o conjunto de utilizadores que recebem 5% ou 8% de uma venda). No final aplicas a percentagem à soma de cada um dos subgrupos para saberes quanto tens que pagar a cada vendedor. Assim só tens que fazer um calculo por subgrupo (no teu caso 2) em vez de um por cada utilizador.

Comment: Entendi, eu pensei que teria como... obrigado!